# Accessing Visual Fox Pro DBF with python

Tags: python, sql, odbc, visual-foxpro

Ok, so our accounting software uses VFP. Yes, I know its old.

They are in the process of updating to Microsoft SQL databases....but I don't have that yet.

I've tried everything under the sun to get to the data with python. This is the best I've come up (below) with but its SLOW. One DBF file is nearly 2gb and this just wont do.

Anyone know of a better solution, ideally I could query it with SQL, but there are no 64bit VFP drivers about.

HELP ME.

```
from dbfread import DBF
import datetime
import os
df = DBF("E:/Opera3VFP/Data/l_stran.dbf")


order_list = ["Reference, Date, Tr Type, Customer Reference, Value, Vat"]

for rec in df:    
    if rec["ST_ACCOUNT"] == "CDL2" and rec["ST_TRDATE"] >= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5):
        order_list.append(f'{rec["ST_TRREF"]}, {rec["ST_TRDATE"]}, {rec["ST_TRTYPE"]}, {rec["ST_CUSTREF"]}, {rec["ST_TRVALUE"]}, {rec["ST_VATVAL"]}')
```

Comment: There is 32 bits VFPOLEDB driver.

Comment: doesnt work for me for some reason

Comment: What doesn't work for you? In your code you would simply filter for a given account and the last 5 days. Isn't it what you are trying to do in your code, in the worst way? I am not a python user, thus no idea how you would use an OLEDB driver from python. If you instead want a sample, say in C# or Go, then I can give you.

Comment: The issue is, the current method i'm implementing is reading the file line by line and its extremely slow. I can use OLEDB drivers etc but when I try to use the 32bit VFP ones it complains "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".  The amount of time it takes to do a basic query is TOO long. I've made something similar in VBA and it takes seconds, this method is more like 30 seconds.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That being said i would be interested in a sample of how it would be written in C# just out of interest.

Answer (score 1):

(This would be a mess as a comment)
C# sample - (in code using a reader, but also added loading to a DataTable in comments):

```
void Main()
{
    //DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=E:\Opera3VFP\Data"))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"select ST_TRREF, ST_TRDATE, ST_TRTYPE, ST_CUSTREF, ST_TRVALUE, ST_VATVAL 
        from l_stran
        where ST_ACCOUNT == ? and 
            ST_TRDATE >= ?",cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@account", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "CDL2";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);

        cn.Open();
        //tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        // using a reader
        var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // do whatever with the row read
        }
        // using a reader
        
        cn.Close();
    }
    // do whatever with tbl
}
```

Provided you have indexes on ST_ACCOUNT and maybe ST_TRDATE, this would be very fast (assuming there isn't an unexpected data distribution - ie: 90% of data belongs to ST_ACCOUNT:CDL2)